# Convert pandas data frame to JSON with strings separated

Tags: python, json, pandas, nlp, sentiment-analysis

**I have a pandas.dataframe named 'df' with the following format:**

| group_name | Positive_Sentiment | Negative_Sentiment |
| --- | --- | --- |
| group1 | helpful, great support | slow customer service, weak interface, bad management |

**I would like to convert this dataframe to a JSON file with the following format:**

```
[{
"Group Name": "group1",
"Postive Sentiment": [
"helpful",
"great support"
],
"Negative Sentiment": [
"slow customer service",
"weak interface",
"bad management"
]
}
]
```

**So far I have used this:**

```
    import json
    b = []
    for i in range(len(df)):
        x={}
        x['Group Name']=df.iloc[i]['group_name']
        x['Positive Sentiment']= [df.iloc[i]['Positive_Sentiment']]
        x['Negative Sentiment']= [df.iloc[i]['Negative_Sentiment']]
        b.append(x)
    
    ##Export
    with open('AnalysisResults.json', 'w') as f:
        json.dump(b, f, indent = 2)
```

**This results in:**

```
[{
"Group Name": "group1",
"Postive Sentiment": [
"helpful,
great support"
],
"Negative Sentiment": [
"slow customer service,
weak interface,
bad UX"
]
}
]
```

**You can see it is quite close. The crucial difference is the double-quotes around the ENTIRE contents of each row (e.g., "helpful, great support") instead of each comma-separated string in the row (e.g., "helpful", "great support"). I would like double-quotes around each string.**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can apply `split(",")` to your columns:

```
from io import StringIO
import pandas as pd
import json

inp = StringIO("""group_name    Positive_Sentiment  Negative_Sentiment
group1  helpful, great support  slow customer service, weak interface, bad management
group2  great, good support     interface meeeh, bad management""")

df = pd.read_csv(inp, sep="\s{2,}")

def split_and_strip(sentiment):
         [x.strip() for x in sentiment.split(",")]

df["Positive_Sentiment"] = df["Positive_Sentiment"].apply(split_and_strip)
df["Negative_Sentiment"] = df["Negative_Sentiment"].apply(split_and_strip)

print(json.dumps(df.to_dict(orient="record"), indent=4))

# to save directly to a file:
with open("your_file.json", "w+") as f:
    json.dump(df.to_dict(orient="record"), f, indent=4)
```

Output:

```
[
    {
        "group_name": "group1",
        "Positive_Sentiment": [
            "helpful",
            "great support"
        ],
        "Negative_Sentiment": [
            "slow customer service",
            "weak interface",
            "bad management"
        ]
    },
    {
        "group_name": "group2",
        "Positive_Sentiment": [
            "great",
            "good support"
        ],
        "Negative_Sentiment": [
            "interface meeeh",
            "bad management"
        ]
    }
]
```

Comment: Thanks. The output looks about right (minus the extra space before second terms), but this is not working when using my original df. How would the code look when taking in my original pandas dataframe (df) as input?

Comment: could you post your dataframe in the question? I just copied it from the table so the formatting might be slightly off... to remove extra space use `strip`

Comment: nevermind. I got it. Thank you. What syntax is needed to then save that JSON as a JSON file?